# variable endpoints for webservice

Tags: url-rewriting, endpoints, web-services

New to wordpress development, I am working on a plugin that retrieves data from a webservice.

I need an endpoint because the retrieved data also depends on the value of the  page's metabox, so in effect the post endpoint variable url is to display a virtual child page.

The desired url would look like this:
**example.com/department-a/individuals/smith.john**
I need the /(page)/ with /(endpoint)/ and /(variable)

The examples I've seen so far, all point to the use of specifically defined variables after the endpoint. Is it possible to have an endpoint with a query variable after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Endpoints](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193888/dynamic-endpoints)

Comment: The Dynamic Endpoints Question/Answer is an interesting approach, however my needs went beyond the use of a _defined rewrite_ : `add_rewrite_rule( '^cars/([^/]*)/?$'`. Herein lies the advantage of using `add_rewrite_endpoint( 'individuals', EP_PAGES );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it might have been working all along, and I just hadn't flushed the rewrites!

```
function my_dept_listing_init() {
    //Easy flush
    if (isset($_GET['flush'])) {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    //endpoint onto which queries are made
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'individuals', EP_PAGES ); 

    //This filter acts as a controller, inject into content
    add_filter('the_content', 'my_dept_listing_content_ctrl');
}
add_action('init', 'my_dept_listing_init');

function my_dept_listing_content_ctrl($content) {
    global $post;

    $getName = get_query_var('individuals');
    $post->post_title = $getName;
    //Etc
}
```

Hope this helps someone!