# adding custom controller called by front-end

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to create *controllers* in Wordpress (WP does not utilize this concept as far as I know)

By controller I understand whole system that retrieves posts.
Example things I need to do:

Create custom url `/fetchEntries` that will call `fetch-entries.php` file directly (for ajax calls)

Create custom url `/places` that will allow me to write own template that will be directly called (normally index.php is called).

What I aim for?
As far as I know to create *controller* I need to:
 - Create page (Admin > Pages)
 - Obtain {Page_ID}
 - Create custom template (page-{Page_ID}.php).

Fragile part of this approach (at last for me) is that someone may press "remove" on that page and destroy whole controller.

Comment: You can add custom endpoints using the Rewrite API http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193888/dynamic-endpoints/196279#196279 or the REST API http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/

Comment: Seen rewrite api. no idea how to *point* it to the file/controller I want

Comment: If you go the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193888/dynamic-endpoints/196279#196279 route, you can either place all the code within the `if ( ! empty( $model ) ) {` or you can add a `require` within the `if ( ! empty( $model ) ) {`